# adding web socket chat into existing nodejs app

Tags: node.js, websocket

I've made nodejs application by [this template](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc). And now I want to add simple websocket chat.

My question is: do I have to completely rewrite that application to add websocket chat or I can to save that structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a chat using Socket.IO (or another library), it's perfectly possible (and probably a best practice even) to separate the two: the regular server and the WebSocket server.

The two aren't tied together.

Comment: You should choose a different port.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the express MVC template, but socket.io does not use express routes and from my experience they exist side by side just fine. Just add your socket.io server code to app.js to test it out and you can use the client side code within any of your express views.

This assumes you're using socket.io of course. I have no experience with other methods of using websockets with node.js.